# Python - One line if-elif-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to condense an if-elif-else statement into one line. I tried:

```
a == 1 ? print "one" : a == 2 ? print "two" : print "none"
```

But I got a syntax-error. I have also tried:

```
print "one" if a == 1 else print "two" if a == 2 else print "none"
```

But I also got a syntax-error.

What can I do to make any of these answers better or create a working answer?

Comment: Question:  why do you want to do this?  Is it for the sake of creating the one-liner, or do you feel that you'll get more clarity out of it?

Comment: @Makoto I want to do this because I don't want to write 6 lines of code. One long line of code would be better.

Comment: Don't confuse clarity and brevity - often shorter is more readable, but if you are honestly telling me that the line of code you are attempting here is clearer than the longer alternative, you have a very different definition of clear.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there isn't a 'one line if-elif-else' statement in Python. There is the [ternary operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), which uses the same keywords and similar syntax, but is a fundamentally different operation with restrictions (primarily that it only supports expressions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary conditional operator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

Comment: @Makoto That has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do. That question wants an if-else statement but I want an if-else-elif statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
print {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}.get(a, 'none')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that dicts were usable in this situation!

Answer (score 11):

The "ternary" operator in Python is an expression of the form

```
X if Y else Z
```

where `X` and `Z` are values and `Y` is a boolean expression.
Try the following:

```
print "one" if a==1 else "two" if a==2 else "none"
```

Here, the value of the expression `"two" if a==2 else "none"` is the value returned by the first when `a==1` is false. (It's parsed as `"one" if a == 1 else ( "two" if a==2 else "none")`.) It returns one of `"one"`, `"two"`, or `"none"`, which is then passed as the sole argument for the `print` statement.

Comment: @avaragecoder, your code is polluted with "print" statements, that doesn't work. This works as expected.

Comment: @xbello Oh. In Ruby that is the same and I guess most of my code related to Ruby.., it was the same. Thank you for the information!

Comment: Note that I state `X` and `Z` are *values*, not *statements*.

Comment: Note that this is a bad side of one-liners. You got a "Syntax Error" and didn't know where it came from. Blamed the "X if Y else Z" but your error was elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Use nested condtional expressions (ternary operator):

```
>>> a = 2
>>> print 'one' if a == 1 else 'two' if a == 2 else 'none'
two
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `dict` instead of nested if

```py
options = {1: "one", 2: "two"}
print options.get(a, 'none')
```

Comment: Where is the option of 'none'?

Comment: There it is :p, on the second parameter of `get` you can put the default value if the key is not found

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple index and conditional:

```
print ('one', 'two', 'none')[0 if a==1 else 1 if a==2 else 2]
```

Alternatively, if a's relationship to an index can be an expression:

```
print ('one', 'two', 'none')[a-1 if a in (1,2) else -1]
```

You can also combine the tuple index method with a dict to produce the index to get something a bit more readable than a straight dict approach (IMHO):

```
print ('one', 'two', 'none')[{1:0,2:1}.get(a, -1)]
```

Comment: +1; this is a not horrible way to do something I would never want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "one" if a == 1 else "two" if a == 2 else "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "one" if a == 1 else("two" if a ==2 else "None")
```